# Ошибка ''Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, php

Есть php страница ,в ней есть две переменные :

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=707dee63a73b4df5af152654210704&q=[London],[long]&days=2') ; 
$cit = file_get_contents('https://api.musement.com/api/v3/cities');
```

Передаю эти переменные в js-функцию :

```
function retWeather(){
        let url = '<?php echo $url ?>'; // здесь,всё работает
        let cit = '<?php echo $cit ?>'; // Ошибка "Unexpected identifier"
```

Не понимаю,в чём проблема

Comment: Это шутка? Вот так прямо переменной в яваскрипт присвоить огромный XML?

Comment: А можно ли вообще-то как-то присвоить ?заранее извиняюсь - новичок

Comment: ЗАЧЕМ? Что с ним потом делать? Оба полученных значения надо сначала **распарсить в РНР**, проверить, содержат ли они нужные данные,  вытащить из них только те элементы, котиорые нужны в JS и передать в **виде JSON**

Comment: Так,в том и дело,что с первым вариантом всё работает ,и потом происходит парсирование JSON.parse(url) и всё отлично ,с этим не работает ,я так понимаю,потому что это XML ,и значит,другой вопрос,есть какие-то встроенные методы в  php ,для парсирование XML ?

Comment: есть, разумеется

Comment: "не работает ,я так понимаю,потому что это XML" - нет, потому что там есть символы вроде `'` и конца строки.

Comment: А не могли бы подсказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cit = <?php echo json_encode($cit) ?>;
```

Comment: Это шутка такая? Паковать XML в джейсон?